# What is the opposite of a decoupled web app?

Tags: web-applications, architecture

If a decoupled app is one where you have a front end that sends requests to a backend then what is the opposite of that? What is a coupled web app? Can you store javascript on the server for frontend functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are called **Muli Page Application**. It's a classic web application where for each request the server does computation and returns a new Web page.

The new architecture becoming widely spread and that you are referring to is **Single Page Application**.

SPAs present the content in an easy, elegant and effective way as it loads all the content on just one single page rather than navigating the user to different pages. SPAs are faster than traditional web applications because they execute the logic in the web browser itself rather than on the server.

In both type of applications, client-side javascript is stored on the server and sent to the client / browser when the latter requests a web page. The amount of javascript with SPAs is obviously greater than MPAs as the logic is pushed to the client side.

Comment: I think there is a name. They can be called as MPAs i.e. Multi page applications.

Comment: Yes makes sense!

Comment: That's right! This is how they are called nowadays! Updating my answer...